# SAP BO - Report from stored proc

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, business-objects

I'm trying to get SAP Business Objects to get a report off of a stored procedure. I had no luck, so I'm now just trying with an example/tutorial how to do it which I found online, and I can't get that to work either.

I'm following:
https://irfansworld.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/what-you-should-know-about-stored-procedure-universe-in-bi-4-0/

I created the objects shown in the exact same way, as shown here:

```
create or replace package emp_package
as type emp_row_type is ref cursor return emp%rowtype;
end emp_package;
/

create or replace 
procedure getEmployeesByDepartment
(
  return_rows_cursor in out emp_package.emp_row_type,
  dept_parameter in emp.deptno%type
)
as begin
  open return_rows_cursor for
  SELECT *
  FROM emp
  WHERE emp.deptno = dept_parameter;
  end;
/
```

I get good results back:
Package EMP_PACKAGE compiled

Procedure GETEMPLOYEESBYDEPARTMENT compiled

But here is where I see a glaring difference... For me, it takes what should only be the out/return parameters, and prompts me as if they are input parameters.

[image: my sap input params]

Even if i say "OK" to this... it doesn't recognize the fields in the "out" cursor as fields for me to show on the report.

I've even tried changing the cursor paramater from "in out" to just "out"... but still no luck.

Any ideas as to why I can't make this example work for me?

Using SAP Universal Design Tool 4.1.

Oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but too long for a comment.

I just tried this with BI4.1 SP Patch 5, and the SP Editor displayed as expected (only showing the DEPT_PARAMETER parameter).

Two possibilities I can think of for the different behavior you're seeing:

One is that there's something going on with the database middleware client that's confusing BO about the parameters.  I'm using Oracle 11g client, and an Oracle Native connection in BO (i.e., not ODBC or JDBC).  If you're using an ODBC or JDBC connection, try the native client instead.

It might be a bug with the specific version of UDT that you're using.  I'd suggest upgrading, or contacting SAP support to see if it's a known issue.

Comment: The issue was corrected once we switched from using the ODBC driver to the Oracle Native connection.